# I'm trying to track delivery status of a message using php( REST api) from Clickatell

Tags: codeigniter, curl, clickatell

In my controller i have

```
public function msgStatus(){
   $this->load->library('clickatell_rest');
   $this->clickatell_rest->getMsgStatus();
}
```

clickatell rest library class

```
  public function getMsgStatus(){   
    $msgId = "message ID here";

    $authToken = urlencode("token here");    

    $ch = curl_init();       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message/$msgId");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "X-Version: 1",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer $authToken"
    ));  
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);  
    print_r($result); exit();
    return $result;
}`
```

when i execute the code the following error displays though my credentials are correct

> {"error":{"code":"001","description":"Authentication
>   failed","documentation":"http://www.clickatell.com/help/apidocs/error/001.htm"}}

i expect my code to return a message status (i.e if the message is queued, failed,delivered to recepient, etc)

Comment: Are you sure you’re supposed to urlencode the token value yourself?

Comment: even when i omit the the urlencode it gives me the same results

Comment: Well then something else must be wrong ... hard to tell what exactly though, when even the link to the documentation from the error message leads only to a 404.

Comment: definitely i just dont know what i am missing in my code

Comment: Can you point us to the proper URL for the API documentation?

Comment: https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/list-of-error-codes-rest/

Comment: Example under https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/using-the-rest-api-rest/ also sends a `Content-Type` header (not sure whether that should make a difference regarding authentication though.)